# Creating a stacked columnchart (Visualisation API)

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I wish to create a stacked column chart, and isStacked(true) is only half the story. How do I make the columns "stacked"? eg: I have a bar of countries, and each bar is divided into the number of industries it has.

I looked at all the AbstractDataType options, but wasnt able to find anything. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. It was simple, just had to add more columns, for a given row. The data in the columns for a given row, creates stacking.